# Error A2006 with MASM from Windows 10 - Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly, x86-64, masm

first of all, sorry for my english. Well, i'm trying to execute some intructions taken from this book, it is called "Modern x86 Assembly Language Programs". And the book is not very clear in how Visual Studio works mixing C++ and MASM. Because literally, the first example gave me an error.

ch02_01.asm(15): error A2006: undefined symbol : r8d

The code is not very extensive:

ch02_01.asm(15): error A2006: undefined symbol : r8d

```
; ------------------------------------------------------
;                       Ch02_01.asm
; ------------------------------------------------------

; extern "C" int IntegerAddSub_(int a, int b, int c, int d);
    
    .model flat
    .code

IntegerAddSub_ proc

; Calculate a + b + c - d
        mov eax, ecx                ;eax = a
        add eax, edx                ;eax = a + b
        add eax, r8d                ;eax = a + b + c
        sub eax, r9d                ;eax = a + b + c - d

        ret                         ;return result to caller
IntegerAddSub_ endp
        end
```

Comment: ``r8d`` and ``r9d`` are registers that are part of x64 native, not 32-bit x86. Be sure you are using the 64-bit version of MASM (``ml64``) if you are going to write 64-bit native assembly. This should be as simple as using the 'x64' platform configuration in your C++ project.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks man, it worked out. I thought i was using a x64 bits configuration for the App. Now it worked just fine,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `r8d` and `r9d` means the assembly is actually x64 native, so it requires using the 64-bit version of MASM.